# How to send Phone application to background in iOS

Tags: ios, avplayer, nsurlsession, avplayerviewcontroller

in my application I have one requirement. I am running my application and playing one video using `AVPlayerViewcontroller`. In middle I received call and I had answer the call and my video will pause.After 5 seconds I will get new url from server to play in `AVPlayerViewcontroller`. That time new url is playing in background can able to hear the sound along with phone call. In this scenario I want to send phone app to background and want to see the video which is playing in avplayer.

Please let me know is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions

Comment: only the user can bring your app in foreground again – you need to focus on handling the media playback properly when your app is inactive.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT:**

> 1. Observe for Interruption Notifications

```
func setupNotifications() {
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                   selector: #selector(handleInterruption),
                                   name: .AVAudioSessionInterruption,
                                   object: nil)
}
```

> 2. Respond to Interruption Notifications

```
@objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let typeValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
        let type = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
            return
    }
    if type == .began {
        // Interruption began, take appropriate actions
    }
    else if type == .ended {
        if let optionsValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt {
            let options = AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
            if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
                // Interruption Ended - playback should resume
            } else {
                // Interruption Ended - playback should NOT resume
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions)

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks. My requirement is i want to minimise phone app so i can see my application which is playing video. Can you please let me know is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think you could minimize the phone app through your app and bring your app to the foreground

Comment: do you have any supporting materials for your proposal? @carrotzoe